# Как интегрировать javascript в php?

Tags: javascript, php

При добавлении яваскрипта в скрипт php появляются синтаксические ошибки.
Подскажите, реален ли вообще данный способ?

```
<?  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
  function vibor() 
  { 
    var kp = 'znachenie';
    document.write(kp); 
  }; 
</script>";
?>
```

Или на что обратить внимание, возможно, какие-то из кавычек экранировать?

Comment: Ошибки javascript'а или php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, напишите что-то типа:

```
echo <<<htmlcode

<script type='text/javascript'> 
    function vibor() 
    { 
      var kp = 'znachenie'; 
      document.write(kp); 
    }; 
  </script>

htmlcode;
```

[Пример использования echo](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 3):

> В этом то всё и дело. Необходимо значение из JS присвоить переменной PHP. Либо сразу же выводить значение через echo или printf.

http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke

Answer (score 2):

Хм, может просто заменить:

```
<?  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
  function vibor() 
  { 
    var kp = 'znachenie';
    document.write(kp); 
  }; 
</script>";
?>
```

На

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function vibor() 
  { 
    var kp = 'znachenie';
    document.write(kp); 
  }; 
</script>";
```

т.е. не открывать бессмысленно тег ради того чтобы вывести статический контент

Comment: В этом то всё и дело. Необходимо значение из JS присвоить переменной  PHP. Либо сразу же выводить значение через echo или printf.